# For + verb-ing at the beginning of a sentece

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, ing

Is the following sentence structure grammatically correct? I mean, I've found a lot of examples that have this structure but not at the beginning of the phrase but with a subject before. Here is an example I'm trying:

> For designing the 3D model of a new tool it's necessary to be sure...

UPDATE: This is the research I've done:

> For + verb-ing: the purpose of an object
>      However, if we are talking about the purpose of an object or an action, we normally use the for + verb-ing pattern. Note that this pattern commonly answers the question: What are they (used) for? Compare the following:
>
> > Schools are for educating children not for entertaining them.
> >     Schools are for learning. Life is for living.
> >     This kitchen knife is especially useful for slicing vegetables.
> >     What's this for? ~ It's for opening oysters. It's much better than a knife.
> >     What's this fifty pound note for? ~ It's for buying food for the weekend.
>
> Note that when the subject of the sentence is a person rather than the thing described, the to + infinitive pattern is also possible:
>
> > I use this small knife to slice vegetables with.
> >     I use this gadget to open shellfish with.

As it is explained it can be used with a subject before, but I haven't been able to find anywhere something explaining the case when For + verb-ing is at the beginning of a sentence

Comment: There is no question here. If you have a particular concern and set of hypotheses regarding something or other here, then please present what your research has uncovered and what your actual question is. Otherwise, this is just proofreading, which is specifically offtopic according to [the ELU FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq). It is unlikely to ever help anyone else, and does not show any kind of good-faith effort at doing your own investigation before coming here.

Comment: I've change the question to share my research. Sorry, this was my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are sentences that start with "for verbing" but that one isn't a particularly good one:

> For eating right away, I prefer Macintosh apples.
>
> For fitting into a small space, the Smart Car is terrific.
>
> For educating children, schools are the usual solution.

So if your question is "can I do this?" the answer is yes. If your question is something else ("What is this called?" "Is there generally a better way to word these sentences?" "Is my particular example grammatical?") then I suggest you edit the question to include an actual question.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatical, but awkward.  A better way of phrasing this would be

> When designing the 3d model of a new tool, it's necessary to be sure ...

Comment: Excellent point @Christi and you get my vote because your alternative keeps the important part of the sentence in the front - namely, "designing the 3D model of a new tool".  Good job! :-)